# How to do queryForList in Spring 4 using Java 8?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data, spring-4

I'm trying to get my head around Spring 4 and Java 8 at the same time. I have a class

```
EmployeeDTO
|-id
|-Emp_Name
|-Address
```

When I try the below code to fetch 1 Employee, it works fine :

```
public EmployeeDTO getEmpoloyeebyID(String empId) {

        return springJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
                (rs, rowNum) -> {
                    return new EmployeeDTO(rs.getString("Emp_Name"), rs
                            .getString("Address"));
                }, empId);
    }
```

But now I want to get a list of objects using the Spring jdbcTemplate and Java 8. I know I might be able to get it through using Mappers. But I want to learn how to do it with Java 8 like the above example. I looks elegant.

```
public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmpoloyeeByAge(Integer age) {

        return springJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,<to-do>, age);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) does not have a method named `queryForList` that you can pass your lambda expression to.

You need to use one of the `query` methods, [the one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-) that takes an SQL string, a `RowMapper` and query arguments:

```
public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployeesByAge(int age) {
    return springJdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, rowNum) ->
        new EmployeeDTO(rs.getString("Emp_Name"), rs.getString("Address")), age);
}
```

Note that your lambda expression matches the `RowMapper` argument of the `query` method.